# .exe file not running after creating it using launch4j

Tags: java, exe, executable-jar, launch4j

I have a .jar file that is perfectly running when I run it using **cmd** command :

> java -cp myjar.jar MainClassName

Now I created .exe file using **launch4j**. But the exe file is not running when I double click on it. It is not showing any error nor output. I haven't used a "**splash**" option in launch4j. Should I have to use it to make the .exe file run? Please help how to run the .exe file.
I can see the log file of my .exe file, created by launch4j, updating only when I run it using launch4j directly. But the output is nothing. Please help me with this.Thankyou

Comment: Does your file use a Frame?  Under Header, u may have to switch the Header type from GUI to Console.

Comment: No it doesn't use a frame.It is a client-server program

Answer (score 0):

If you **don't** use a **JFrame** in your application then you need to use **Console** instead of GUI. Once check it. And also use **jar2Exe** application for converting jar to Exe file.